# Can heat generated by a falling object in a liquid be used as a perpetual motion machine?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, fluid-dynamics, energy-conservation, perpetual-motion

I have a question regarding perpetual motion. I have tried to debunk it but I cant seem to find anything wrong with the concept. I think i am missing something so please help.

There is a solid suspended on top of an insulated container full of liquid. It's density would cause it to sink. However, some of kinetic energy from the solid falling is converted into heat energy. This heat energy is enough to raise the temperature of the solid to a point where it's density will decrease to the point where it starts floating. When the solid is at the top, energy is slowly released from the system, and the process repeats.

Wouldn't this system generate far more work then the potential energy that was put into it?

Answer (score 3):

The system will equilibrate at the submersion depth where the densities are equal. ([It may oscillate around this point or not.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping)) At this asymptotic equilibration point, no more energy can be extracted.

Answer (score 1):

You say **"insulated container"**, and then **"when the solid is at the top, energy is slowly released"**. So that released heat can't escape the container, and therefore necessarily raises the temperature of the contained liquid. And thus, after several cycles, it'll be hot enough so that the solid's density is always low enough to keep it perpetually floating.

And, of course, if the container weren't insulated, you'd just be doing work between the two temperatures (*i.e.,* cooler atmospheric sink, and the heated-up-solid/liquid source). But I'll leave it as an exercise for you to draw the PVT-diagram, and figure out what thermodynamic cycle we're talking about **:)**